# repopulating data in table #gridjs

Tags: javascript, gridjs

so i know the updateConfig() / forceRender() methods in gridjs, but is it possible to workaround the 'redrawing table'? I'm looking for a function/method that repopulate tables data with persisting view/search/filter options.

Thanks <3